# PHP Lazy Boolean Evaluation

Tags: php, lazy-evaluation

I have a conditional statement thus:

```
if($boolean && expensiveOperation()){ ...}
```

Does PHP have lazy boolean evaluation, i.e. will it check `$boolean` and if it is false not bother performing the expensive operation? If so, what order should I put my variables?

Comment: I would generally refrain from putting 2 operations in the same line of code if they are not inherently related. It makes readability difficult and you don't gain computing time or resources.

Comment: Apols for my incorrect answer (now deleted). I thought I remembered trying this out and finding it didn't work, but I'm obviously mistaken.

Comment: @Nathan At least you got a Peer Pressure badge :)

Comment: @Alin Purcaru Is that a good thing? :)

Comment: @Nathan It shows you're responsible... or afraid of loosing reputation points.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes it does.  It's called short-circuit evaluation.  See the comments on the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)...

As for the order, it performs the checks based on [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php#language.operators.precedence) and then left to right.  So:

```
A || B || C
```

Will evaluate A first, and then B only if A is false, and C only if both A and B are false...

But

```
A AND B || C
```

Will always evaluate `B || C`, since `||` has a higher precedence than `AND` (not true for `&&`).

Comment: if you *want* the non-shor-circuit evaluation you can use a single & which would be a boolean union function. It would compute both values and then try to perform an AND between them.

Comment: @Mikhail: Yes.  But you must be careful as the singe `&` is actually a bit-wise operator.  So `true & 2` would be false (since `true` is `00000001`, and `2` is `00000010`, so the `AND` would be `00000000`)...

Comment: @Alin: Thanks!  Dam google took me to the wrong docs...  Fixed in the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, PHP does [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 3):

PHP does have short circuit evaluation. Your example would be the proper use of it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_and_scripting_languages