# Why is the code that enables the .env file to be loaded located in bootstrap.php?

Tags: php, cakephp, environment-variables, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I'm using CakePHP 4 and I'm setting up my development environment. To enable the use of the .env file I uncomment the block found in `bootstrap.php`, as explained in the [Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/configuration.html#environment-variables):

```
// if (!env('APP_NAME') && file_exists(CONFIG . '.env')) {
//     $dotenv = new \josegonzalez\Dotenv\Loader([CONFIG . '.env']);
//     $dotenv->parse()
//         ->putenv()
//         ->toEnv()
//         ->toServer();
// }
```

I was wondering why this bit of code is not located in for example the `app_local.php`, because loading the .env file is something that is environment specific.
E.g. in development I do want my app to load the .env file, but in production I do not want this. But since `bootstrap.php` is present in both development and production environments, the application will always perform the check if it has to load the .env file, which is not necessary in production.

Am I enabling the .env file correctly? Or should the Dotenv loader code in `bootstrap.php` always be commented out in production? If so, would it not make more sense to place it in `app_local.php`?

Comment: In production you can simply remove said file or rename it. In general, this file is used for non-production environments (development, testing etc)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I know the .env file should not be used in production environments, but my concern is about the `if (!env('APP_NAME') && file_exists(CONFIG . '.env')) {}` statement. In a production environment this statement shouldn't have to be present, but `bootstrap.php` is not environment specific and used across all environments.

Comment: It should be fine to be used in production, why not? If your concern about that check, then if first check fails, the second one will not be executed due to [short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167939/will-an-if-statement-stop-checking-if-the-first-or-condition-is-met-in-php) logic.

Comment: True! My question is not as much about performance or security, but more about keeping the code organized. In my opinion, if something is not needed in an environment, the code should not be included. That would be achieved by putting the check into an environment specific file, like `app_local.php`. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Well, that’s more of a personal preference and your goal can be accomplished in different ways.